Problem with responsive fonts only in android mobile app flutter
I have problem with scale fonts in my app, on iOS fonts are good in every small and large devices, but in android no - in simulator everything is good, but when i send .apk to my friend (samsung a54) this fonts is so large! Now i tried to use sizer package from pub.dev, but this package will scale my fonts on ios too - what can i do with this 'problem'?
I tried to use responsive framework (not working with latest flutter version) and sizer package.

Try using Flutter Screen Utils package or use LayoutBuilder. It should solve your problem.
